# How to display a value in textbox with radio button click in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, radio-button

I am new to php and I am trying to display a value ($total_discount) to a textbox when radio button is clicked. But whenever my radio button is clicked, it only outputs a text 'undefined'. This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function insertDiscount(getDiscount) {
      document.getElementById("discount").value = getDiscount;
   }
</script>

<?php
   $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
   $discount_a = 0.10;
   $discounted_price;
   $total_discount;

   if(isset($item_price)){
       $discounted_price = $item_price * $discount_a;
       $total_discount = $discounted_price * $quantity;
   }
?>

<input type="text" name="discount" id="discount" value="">
<input type="radio" name="discounts" id="discount_A" onclick="insertDiscount(''.$total_discount);">
<label for="discount_A">10% Discount</label>
```

Comment: Take a look at the source code or "inspect" the element: does `onclick="insertDiscount()` hold the value you want? Most likely not, since you need to `echo` it: `onclick="insertDiscount(<?php echo $total_discount ?>);"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="discounts" id="discount_A" onclick="insertDiscount(''.$total_discount);">
```

- To output the value of `$total_discount` you need to `<?= $total_discount; ?>` which will echo the value

So your final result will look something like this.

```
onclick="insertDiscount('<?= $total_discount; ?>')">
```

Comment: Hi thank you for replying, I have tried this but unfortunately, there is nothing being displayed on the textbox when the radiobtn is clicked.

Comment: @WiloWisk - Try manually setting a value for `$total_discount` when it is declared. I have a feeling `isset($item_price)` is always false.

Comment: @WiloWisk - I just realized you do need to actually call the function. I've updated my above answer to remove the bind stuff. Been using react for too long, I've forgotten the old ways...

Comment: Hello thank you for your patience. I have set a value to `$total_discount` to 0, now it displays a 0 to the textbox but it still would not compute the formula `$total_discount = $discounted_price * $quantity`

Comment: @WiloWisk - Progress! If I had to guess `isset($item_price)` is probably always `false` since I do not see it anywhere else in your code. Can you manually update that to be `true`? Or can you verify that `$item_price` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not rendering the value of the variable `$total_discount`.

Chanage

`onclick="insertDiscount(''.$total_discount);"`

to

`onclick="insertDiscount(<?php echo($total_discount); ?>)"`

to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

- The output is undefined because `$total_discount` variable is undefined.
- First you can check `$total_discount` is not null.
- if `$total_discount` is a not null then you can pass `$total_discount` in javascript function `insertDiscount()` function.
- if `$total_discount` is null or undefined then you can assign `$total_discount` variable value and pass in javascript function `insertDiscount()` function.

Example code

```
<?php if(isset($total_discount)): ?>
    <input type="radio" name="discounts" id="discount_A" onclick="insertDiscount(<?=$total_discount?>);">
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- First you can assign $total_discount variable value then pass it -->
    <?php $total_discount = 10; ?>
    <input type="radio" name="discounts" id="discount_A" onclick="insertDiscount(<?=$total_discount?>);">
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for replying, I have tried this but it only outputs a 10 on the textbox. Is there a way to output the `$total_discount = $discounted_price * $quantity` on the textbox from radiobtn click?

Comment: But sir you can assign first `$discounted_price` and `$quantity` variable value. and after write `$total_discount = $discounted_price * $quantity` statement and use it.